# Download file from Azure Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

The official snippet code for downloading a blob from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=environment-variable-windows#download-blobs) is:

```py
# Download the blob to a local file
# Add 'DOWNLOAD' before the .txt extension so you can see both files in the data directory
download_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, str.replace(local_file_name ,'.txt', 'DOWNLOAD.txt'))
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container= container_name) 
print("\nDownloading blob to \n\t" + download_file_path)

with open(download_file_path, "wb") as download_file:
 download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob(blob.name).readall())
```

The problem is that `readall` reads the blob content to the memory. Giant blobs (hundreds of Gigabytes) cannot be held in memory.

I didn't find a way to download a blob directly to the file (can use a buffer internally, but not hold all the file's content). Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In case of large blobs, you would want to use [`download_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download-blob) method in [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python). This method allows you to read a range of data as a stream.

The way this would work is you call this method multiple times and each time when you call it, you would set the `offset` and `length` parameter to a different value.

For example, let's say your blob size is 10MB and you want to download it in chunks of 1MB, when you call this method first time, you will set the offset as `0` and length as `1048576` (1 MB) and you will get a stream of 1MB data. Next time you call this method, you set the offset as `1048576` and so on.

This way you will be able to progressively download a blob.

Comment: The original code snippet uses `download_blob` from `BlobClient` but it also uses `readall`. Is there any way to download it in chucks to file via the Blob API itself?

Comment: No. It used [`download_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-download-blob) from `ContainerClient`. You can also specify the `offset` and `length` there to partially read the blob.